# iOS - UIWebView is not navigating for Sub links in HTML String

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have loaded `HTML String` in web view which contains some links in it for Web service call.

It calls web service properly and also loads new data from web service response into same web view.

But it is not allowing me to come back from new page to previous one.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use below UIWebView method  -

```
if ([myWebView canGoBack]) 
{
     [myWebView goBack];
}
```